# How to define a {key: classType} map?

Tags: typescript

Here's what I've got:

```
type StructureManagerMap<T extends StructureConstant=StructureConstant> = { [K in T]?: StructManager<ConcreteStructure<K>>}
```

Where `StructManager` is:

```
export abstract class StructManager<T extends Structure> {
    constructor(readonly roomInfo: RoomInfo, readonly struct: T) {}

    abstract buildCache?(): ScreepsReturnCode
    abstract gameLoop(): ScreepsReturnCode
    abstract drawVisuals?(): ScreepsReturnCode
}
```

And I'm trying:

```
const managerMap: StructureManagerMap = {
    [STRUCTURE_SPAWN]: SpawnManager, // <-- error here
}
```

Where `SpawnManager` is:

```
export default class SpawnManager extends StructManager<StructureSpawn>{
  ...
}
```

And `STRUCTURE_SPAWN` is just some string constant.

The error I'm getting is:

> TS2739: Type 'typeof SpawnManager' is missing the following properties from type 'StructManager': roomInfo, struct, gameLoop
> Did you mean to use 'new' with this expression?

I *think* it's expecting `SpawnManager` to be an *instance* of `StructManager` but what I really want is to be a class that extends `StructManager`

Writing it like this:

```
{ [K in T]?: typeof StructManager<ConcreteStructure<K>>}
```

Isn't even valid syntax though. How do I define that object as a mapping of constants to classes that extend `StructManager<ConcreteStructure<K>>`?

Here's a (updated) [self-contained example on TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBXAxsR8IGED2A7AzsAIa7BQC8UARPmEQO65VQA+1w29E8VA3AFD8AlqW4AzIsmhwkqdBAA8AFSgQAHsAi4AJvlgIUaDDgLFSFfbKNY8hEsAB8UAN78o7qAAshwfAC4oXEQAWwAjbgEAX2FReAkpS0N5GDpGVQ0tXUS5DAUaVKYHVw9VXG4AcxAAoLCI-miRTTjJaQMciCVObnTNHT0ZJNyqDi4eIrcPLQqQTCI6ZB8qwJDw+CjBUEgoE2QMTQH25R7M-rbrEztSJ0oVdV6s-IYmCfcAfmzrFKeXqADbjL67C6PB+7wO1k6ox+1QgADc6vx1GBsPAyERQoR4JIyMgADZEfCnKwAWRIRHK3COdxOH3kTmKHmQtjOKIAFBgiNo8LiQFBMYY-gBKFzRErozHYqDlIjBCAAGWw2DArMF1RW3HqG3ArSs8lJuHJ3FJYCpAKy4PkFzMwHIFuMzPs1xcUAA2gBpKAiKBKAC6rwCzjK9FZ-h2ewgdsUbocqo++sN8AUYYg+zO8gU0YckWi-DxBP6BXjFPgx0B4KLlMjX0Y4xK0tlCqVKpcPxKe3QuCgAAYftEc0zTFBgmTi-5aRgK-BjRYGe4XY9GFQfQFq7hJwAaTXCMSs4cG0fz2hPJfC2dQAeEPmFkfdShBoc3+D4Q8FJes5zeXx+ABs66m8EqPwAFZIkFeogA)

It mostly works now, but I don't like having to repeat the constructor for `StructManager` to `new(...)`

---

Full code for posterity:

```
type StructureConstant = "spawn" | "tower";

interface Structure<T extends StructureConstant = StructureConstant> {
    hits: number;
}
interface StructureSpawn extends Structure<"spawn">{
    energy: number;
}
interface StructureTower extends Structure<"tower">{
    energyCapacity: number;
}

type ConcreteStructure<T extends StructureConstant> = T extends "spawn"
    ? StructureSpawn
    : T extends "tower"
    ? StructureTower
    : never;

export abstract class StructManager<T extends Structure> {
    constructor(readonly struct: T) {}
    abstract gameLoop(): number
}

type StructureManagerMap<T extends StructureConstant=StructureConstant> = { [K in T]?: {new(s:ConcreteStructure<K>): StructManager<ConcreteStructure<K>>}}

class SpawnManager extends StructManager<StructureSpawn>{
    gameLoop() {
        return 0
    }
}

const managers: StructureManagerMap = {
    ["spawn"]: SpawnManager,
}

if(managers["spawn"]) {
    const spawnManager = new managers["spawn"]({hits:6,energy:5})
}
```

Comment: In type position, the name of a class refers to the type of an object created by newing that class. In value position, the name of the class refers to the class itself, the thing you new. The type of this letter value, that is to say the type of the class object itself, is written `typeof ClassName` in typescript, hence the error

Comment: If you're looking for a (zero-argument) constructor signature it's `new () => YourInstanceType` or `{new(): YourInstanceType}`.  If you use that instead of `typeof` it should work.  But there's lots of other stuff going on in this example that's strange and not seemingly relevant to the question "how do I refer to class constructor types":

Comment: People tend to write [empty classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) and [unused type parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--) in example code, but that does weird things (see links) and is best avoided... it's harder to focus on the actual issue at hand when the compiler surprises us by saying that all these different type names refer to the same mutually compatible `{}` type.

Comment: By not [initializing your class properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization) you get errors.  And by not checking for or [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) the presence of an optional property like `managers.spawn` before calling it, you get errors.  These unrelated errors also distract from the question, so ideally you'd modify the example code to avoid them and constitute a true [mcve].

Comment: @jcalz I filled out the example some more and used your `new()` idea -- it looks like that works!